# How to protect database to delete by other app database

Tags: android, sqlite

Please give me idea about that if possible.

1. I created first app with mydb.db database and store DB in sdcard.
2. created second app with same DB name mydb.db and storing the same place.

After running first app, it is creating the DB in sdcard but second app deleting this DB and creating own database.

How to protect first database to delete by second db?

logcat:

```
01-31 12:22:15.649: D/dalvikvm(25919): GC_EXPLICIT freed 77K, 4% free 6383K/6599K, paused 4ms+6ms
01-31 12:30:29.389: D/dalvikvm(25919): GC_EXPLICIT freed 10K, 4% free 6377K/6599K, paused 3ms+3ms

01-31 12:31:41.029: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(6547): sqlite returned: error code = 26, msg = file is encrypted or is not a database, db=/mnt/sdcard/sdcard/appdatabase
01-31 12:31:41.029: E/SqliteDatabaseCpp(6547): CREATE TABLE android_metadata failed
01-31 12:31:41.039: E/DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler(6547): Corruption reported by sqlite on database: /mnt/sdcard/sdcard/appdatabase
01-31 12:31:41.079: E/DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler(6547): deleting the database file: /mnt/sdcard/sdcard/appdatabase
01-31 12:31:41.409: V/creating DB(6547): its done
01-31 12:31:41.479: V/TLINE(6547): new: android.text.TextLine@40668ae0
```

Comment: Please only use code block formatting for *actual codeblocks*, and quote blocks for *actual quotes*.

Answer (score 2):

Files on the SD card can be accessed by all apps (and by everybody else if the SD card is plugged into another machine).

If you don't want other apps to access you data, you have to store it in you app's private data directory on the internal storage.
However, this doesn't prevent it from being deleted either, because *the user* is allowed to delete an app's data.

Comment: but what happened if app is unistalled...my DB also will be deleted.

Comment: we can protect database by using sqlcipher also..dont worry about that.